# How to filter elements of an array based on a property inside double nested array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Well, i have a complicated issue. at least it is complicated for myself.

So i have an Array which has an Array that has an Array in it.

and i want to filter The very top array based on properties inside the deepest array.

Lets say i have this Array of objects

```
var garages = [{
        "GarageId": 1,
        "GarageName": "Garage_001",
        "Sections": [{
            "SectionId": 1,
            "Name": "Section_002",
            "Cars": [{
                "Id": 5,
                "Model": "Bmw"
            }, {
                "Id": 6,
                "Model": "Mercedes"
            }]
        }, {
            "SectionId": 2,
            "Name": "Section_003",
            "Cars": [{
                "Id": 8,
                "Model": "Toyota"
            }, {
                "Id": 6,
                "Model": "Mercedes"
            }]
        }]

    },
    {
        "GarageId": 6,
        "GarageName": "Garage_006",
        "Sections": [{
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Section_007",
            "Cars": [{
                "Id": 5,
                "Model": "Bmw"
            }, {
                "Id": 6,
                "Model": "Mercedes"
            }]
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Section_003",
            "Cars": [{
                "Id": 8,
                "Model": "Toyota"
            }, {
                "Id": 6,
                "Model": "Mercedes"
            }]
        }]

    }
]
```

And i want to retrieve a list of garages that contain a Hyundai for example. how can i do it? 
i have been trying for hours and this is what i came up with. it may be a stupid piece of code but i just got confused dealing with this much nested Arrays!

So my code is this:

```
garages: any[] = [];
selectedCarModel: number: 8;

filterOnCarModel(carId) {
    this.garages = getGaragesFromServed();

    this.selectedCarModel = this.CarModels.find(c => c.Id == id);
    let filteredArray = this.garages
        .filter((garage) =>
            garage.Sections).
        filter((section) =>
            study.Cars.find((car) => car.Id == carId));
    this.garages = filteredArray;
}
```

Thank you for understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredGarages = garages.filter(garage => 
    garage.Sections.filter(section => 
         section.Cars.filter(car => car.Model.indexOf("Bmw")>=0)
   .length > 0)
.length > 0)
```

Comment: You can replace filter calls with find(); result will be same. Find will terminate on the first match, hence more efficient.

Comment: Agreed, filter only needed at top level. Section and cars can use find